# Logstash not able to connect to Elasticsearch deployed on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, connection, logstash

I have deployed Logstash and elasticsearch pod on EKS cluster. When I am checking the logs for logstash pod it is showing unreachable elasticserach server. Though my elasticsearch is up and running. Please find below yaml files and log error.

configMap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "logstash-configmap-development"
  namespace: "development"
  labels:
    app: "logstash-development"
data:
  logstash.conf: |-
    input {
         http {
         
      }
    }
    
    filter {
        json {
            source => "message"
        }
    }
    output {
      elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["https://my-server.com/elasticsearch-development/"]
            index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
        
        stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
      }
    }
```

deployment.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  kind: "Deployment"
  metadata: 
    name: "logstash-development"
    namespace: "development"
  spec: 
    selector: 
      matchLabels: 
        app: "logstash-development"
    replicas: 1
    strategy: 
      type: "RollingUpdate"
      rollingUpdate: 
        maxSurge: 1
        maxUnavailable: 1
    minReadySeconds: 5
    template: 
      metadata: 
        labels: 
          app: "logstash-development"
      spec: 
        containers: 
          - 
            name: "logstash-development"
            image: "logstash:7.10.2"
            imagePullPolicy: "Always"
            env: 
              - 
                name: "XPACK_MONITORING_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS"
                value: "https://my-server.com/elasticsearch-development/"
                
              -
                name: "XPACK_MONITORING_ELASTICSEARCH_URL"
                value: "https://my-server.com/elasticsearch-development/"
                
              -
              
                name: "SERVER_BASEPATH"
                value: "logstash-development"
                
                
                
            securityContext:
                privileged: true
                
            ports: 
              - 
                containerPort: 8080
                protocol: TCP
                
            volumeMounts:
                -
                  name: "logstash-conf-volume"
                  mountPath: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/"
                  
        volumes:
            -
              name: "logstash-conf-volume"
              configMap:
                 name: "logstash-configmap-development"
                 items:
                    - key: "logstash.conf"
                      path: "logstash.conf"
        imagePullSecrets: 
          - 
            name: "logstash"
```

service.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "Service"
  metadata: 
    name: "logstash-development"
    namespace: "development"
    labels: 
      app: "logstash-development"
  spec: 
    ports: 
      - 
        port: 55770
        targetPort: 8080
    selector: 
      app: "logstash-development"
```

Logstash pod log error

```
[2021-06-09T08:22:38,708][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://my-server.com/elasticsearch-development/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://my-server.com/elasticsearch-development/][Manticore::ConnectTimeout] connect timed out"}
```

Note:- Elasticsearch is up and running. And when I hit the logstash url it is giving as status ok.

I have checked with elasticsearch cluster-ip, their logstash is able to connect with Elasticsearch, but when I am giving ingress path url it is not able to connect to elasticsearch.

Also from the logs, I noticed it is taking incorrect url for elasticsearch.

My elasticsearch url is something like this:- https://my-server.com/elasticserach

but instead logstash is looking for https://my-server.com:9200/elasticsearch

With this url (https://my-server.com:9200/elasticsearch) elasticsearch is not accessible as a result it is giving connection timeout.

Can someone tell why it is taking (https://my-server.com:9200/elasticsearch) and not (https://my-server.com/elasticsearch)

Comment: Is elasticsearch running in kubernetes as well or externally?

Comment: @whites11, elastisearch running in kubernetes only

Comment: so can you maybe share the actual URL you set in logstash rather than the placeholder you set? It should be a private URL and thus should not cause any security problem.

Comment: @whites11, sorry that I won't be able to share but it is an https url, followed by ingress path url

Comment: What I mean is, if logstash and elasticsearch are running in the same kubernetes cluster you should use the internal service name to reach ES from LS

Comment: You mean to say like, I should give Elasticsearch's cluster-ip? I have use the service as cluster-ip

Comment: if your elasticsearch kubernetes service is named "es" in namespace "monitoring" and listening to port 9200 in HTTPS the URL should be `https://es.monitoring:9200`. You never want to use IP addresses on kubernetes

Comment: I have added as https://es.monitoring:9200 in deployment.yaml as well as configmaps but still giving the same error in the logs

Comment: I suggest taking a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/

Comment: @whites11 I have got the problem, my elasticsearch url is https://my-server.com/elasticsearch, where as logstash is taking https://my-server.com:9200/elasticsearch and on url (https://my-server.com:9200/elasticsearch) elasticsearch is not accessible. Any solution or reason why logstash is taking (https://my-server.com:9200/elasticsearch). even though I have  mentioned (https://my-server.com/elasticsearch)  in my deployment.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to connect logstash with elasticsearch, if you are using elasticsearch with dns name, logstash by default will take the port of elasticsearch as 9200, so in my case it was taking the elasticsearch url as https://my-server.com:9200/elasticsearch-development/. But with that url, elasticsearch was not accessible, it was only accessible with (https://myserver.com/elasticsearch-development/). So I need to add the https port i.e 443 in my elasticsearch url, through which the logstash would be able to connect to elasticserach (https://my-server.com:443/elasticsearch-development/)

Long story short:-

In deployment.yaml file under env variable XPACK_MONITORING_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS and XPACK_MONITORING_ELASTICSEARCH_URL given the value as https://my-server.com:443/elasticsearch-development/

Same value was given in logstash.conf file.